# What is rightmost sentential forms?

Tags: formal-grammars, compilers

I'm solving some past job interview problems.
I met an embarrassing question about compilers.

The question is :

> Consider the following grammar, with start symbol $E$:
>
> \begin{align*} E &\rightarrow E \ast E\\  &\quad \mid E ~/~ E\\ 
>  &\quad \mid E + E\\  &\quad \mid E - E\\  &\quad \mid (E)\\  &\quad
>  \mid a \mid b \mid c \mid \ldots \mid x \mid y \mid z \end{align*}
>
> The following strings are legal derivations from this grammar:
>
> 1. $a \ast b + c$
> 2. $( a - b ) \ast c$
> 3. $a ~/~ ( b – c)$
>
> Which of the above are rightmost sentential forms?

When I was an undergraduate student, I learned that rightmost(leftmost) sentential form is result of rightmost(leftmost) derivation.
so, I think if $1,2,3$ are legal derivations form above grammar then absolutely all of $1,2,3$ are rightmost sentential form.
If I'm correct, above question is very worthless.

Is there any counter example that is not rightmost sentential form of the grammar $G$ although it is a legal derivation from $G$?

OR

Is there another definition about rightmost sentential form corresponding to above question? I have googled "rightmost sentential form" but there are few results and most of them is the definition that I already know.

Comment: LR parsers find right-most derivations, LL parsers left-most derivations. I don't know what a "rightmost sentential form" is supposed to be.

Answer (score 7):

I found other answers here confusing, so let me explain it clearly here-

Definitions:

> **A sentential form** is any string derivable from the start symbol. Note that this includes the forms with non-terminals at intermediate steps as well.
>
> **A right-sentential form** is a sentential form that occurs in a step of rightmost derivation (RMD).
>
> **A sentence** is a sentential form consisting only of terminals

The examples in your question are all [sentences](https://web.cs.wpi.edu/%7Ekal/PLT/PLT2.1.2e.html). And since any way of derivation (including RMD) ultimately leads to a sentence, technically **all sentences are right-sentential as well as left-sentential forms**. So there isn't any counter example which you asked for.

Clarifying Examples : Page 2 of [this link](https://www.univ-orleans.fr/lifo/Members/Mirian.Halfeld/Cours/TLComp/res1-CG.pdf)

Comment: "since any way of derivation (including RMD) ultimately leads to a sentence, technically all sentences are right-sentential as well as left-sentential forms" -- there is a logical error in this sentence.  A proof that all sentences are right-sentential and left-sentential requires some work.  (Note that any way of derivation leads to a sentential form, but not all sentential forms are right-sentential, etc.)

Answer (score 3):

The grammar can be parsed both left-most and right-most.

`a∗b+c` can be derived left-most:

```
E 
E * E
E * E + E
a * E + E
a * b + E
a * b + e
```

and also right-most (correct precedence:)

```
        E 
    E + E 
E * E + E 
E * E + c 
E * b + c 
a * b + c
```

Only in the following form the grammar is both unambiguously left-recursive and arithmetically correct

```
S → E

E → T | E + T | E - T

T → F | T * F | T / F | (E)

F → a | b | c | ... | 1 | 2 | 3 | ...
```

Comment: I don't know how this answer is helping answer the question, except to know that each line in your second example is a right-sentential form.

Answer (score 1):

I agree, that all the above examples given are rightmost sentential forms. I am not quite sure, how much this is correct, but I thought of a slight modification to definition of right sentential form. Here it goes,

> The **right sentential form** is the sentential form in which the input string when parsed from right-to-left and reduced whenever possible would give final output as the start symbol

Here reduction operation means to replace the symbol or set of symbols by the non-terminal symbol such that the symbol(s) satisfies some rule corresponding to that non-terminal symbol.

I thought of this definition because when I made the parse tree for the example strings given, I found that **first example** produced two parse trees, but both of them when parsed from right to left and reduced accordingly will ultimately lead to the start symbol.

Comment: I think the above definition is incorrect. 
A sentential form is any string (including ones with non-terminals) derivable from the start symbol. A right-sentential form is any string that occurs during making a rightmost derivation. 
Examples : Page 2 of [this link](https://www.univ-orleans.fr/lifo/Members/Mirian.Halfeld/Cours/TLComp/res1-CG.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

Right derivation: when you select right most non terminal everytime to derive the string from G then it will result in the right sentetntial form
If there is a legal derivation for G it must have atmost one right or left derivation, which results in right sentential form or left sentential form.

this can be proved for example consider a grammar G which derives the strings not by left or right derivations but by mixed , so now i can rearrange the productions to produce only the right and then the left, it is a simple arrangement as we do not have any conditions when to apply the the production rules.So i think there will be no grammar G for which there will be a derivation but not a right most derivation tree

Answer (score 0):

The answer is (iii).

Considering precedence rules, * operator has more precedence than + operator, but bracket () has more precedence than *.

So in (i), you start from the left where you have *, as there is no bracket in the string.

In (ii), you still start from the left due to the use of bracket for the + operator which make it to have higher precedence than *.

But in (iii), you must start from the right because of the use of bracket on the operator with the lesser precedence (+).

Comment: So the other answers are wrong?

Comment: Also, perhaps you could be a little less playful in your answer, say not starting it with a greeting.

Comment: The precedence rules you mention may be standard, but they are in no way implied by the grammar given.